# Curl Script Returning False

Tags: php, curl

I am getting `bool(false)` when I `var_dump $information` I can access the API fine via the browser just not via the code below why?

```
    $json = file_get_contents('API URL');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pw");
    curl_error($ch);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $information = json_decode($result, true);

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what's the contents of the `API` file?

Comment: Have you check for errors with http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php? That would be the first thing to do.

Comment: What does var_dump($json) show?

Comment: @H2CO3 its a standard json api url file

Comment: @JessMcKenzie but what is its **content**?

Comment: @Iznogood HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
$json = file_get_contents('API URL');
```

should be

```
 $json = 'API_URL';
```